# Is there a way to check the processor of a MacBook without setting it up?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, serial-number

I am trying to check the processor number of a MacBook Pro without setting it up.

Upon looking up the serial number on Apple's website, it says that it's a "MacBook Pro (16 inch, 2021)." However, it does not specify whether it's an M1 Pro or M1 Max chip.

How would I which CPU this MacBook Pro contains?

Comment: Serial number lookup is no longer feasible. Why can’t you bring an external drive with macOS to boot the Mac or use internet recovery to inspect the system information? Neither of these require you to set up the internal storage on the Mac with a user account.

Answer (score 1):

"About This Mac" under the Apple menu contains the chip type.

[image]

You can see this information when booting to Recovery, so no user account setup is necessary.

Comment: They said "WIthout setting it up".

Comment: @Barmar You can do this in Recovery mode. I'm assuming that they haven't erased the OS and other partitions, of course.